# Customized processing to convert rows to Columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot

I know that lots of questions have already been asked about SQL table formatting but I couldn't find any solution to my current problem.

My problem is, I have a table containing data about companies along with the employees linked to those companies.

```
Company_ID  Person_ID   Name                     Departement_ID
1           1           aaa                             1         
1           2           bbb                             1         
1           3           ccc                             1         
1           4           ddd                             2         
2           5           eee                             1         
2           6           fff                             2         
2           7           ggg                             2
```

I would like to display a sample of 2 employees data per departement for each company. The result for Departement 1 would then be like this:

```
Company_ID Contact1ID_Dpt1 Contact1Name_Dpt1 Contact2ID_Dpt1 Contact2Name_Dpt1
1          1               aaa               2               bbb
2          5               eee               NULL            NULL
```

Can someone please help me solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

similar to Gordon's example, but you dont really need to include department in your group by or your row_number().. if you'd like to add a Departement filter you would add it in your subquery..

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (
     Company_ID INT,
     Person_ID INT,
     [Name] VARCHAR(MAX),
     Departement_ID INT
    )
INSERT  INTO @Table1
VALUES
        (1,1,'aaa',1),
        (1,2,'bbb',1),
        (1,3,'ccc',1),
        (1,4,'ddd',2),
        (2,5,'eee',1),
        (2,6,'fff',2),
        (2,7,'ggg',2)

DECLARE @Departement INT = 1
SELECT
    Company_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN Person_ID END) AS Contact1ID_Dpt,
    MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN [Name] END) AS Contact1Name_Dpt,
    MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN Person_ID END) AS Contact2ID_Dpt,
    MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN [Name] END) AS Contact2Name_Dpt
FROM
    (SELECT 
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY Company_ID ORDER BY Person_ID) AS seqnum 
    FROM 
        @Table1 t
    WHERE   --add your department filter here.
        Departement_ID = @Departement
    ) t

GROUP BY
    Company_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a pivot which can be easily done using `row_number()` and conditional aggregation.

```
select company_id, department_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then name end) as name1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then name end) as name1.
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (company_id, department_id order by newid()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by company_id, department_id;
```

You can add a filter to get only one department, if you like.